# How to change placeholder text in Ag-grid filter?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am using Ag-grid and i just want to change placeholder text of filter.Do i need to use custom filter or this can be done via other ways as well.Please help

Below is the link of image. In which i tried to show 'filter' text for placeholder which i need to change.

[image: Example]

Comment: Could you post a code example of your issue?

Comment: @Juan Please check the image link i have provided above.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't partially modify this inbuilt feature, but you can create own `filterComponent` for that. See docs:  https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-component

Comment: @un.spike so just to change a placeholder  , we need to create a custom filter right ?

Comment: @gauravpatni yes

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, ag-Grid customization options of the default text filter are very poor.

But you can achieve your goal with a simple DOM manipulation:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('ag-floating-filter-input')).forEach((obj) => {
  if (obj.attributes['disabled']) { // skip columns with disabled filter
    return;
  }
  obj.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Filter...');
});
```

This will grab all filter text inputs of ag-Grid (by 'ag-floating-filter-input') class and set the placeholder value to your value.

Comment: Where should I put this function? I was able to get the filter value using jquery but I don't know where exactly to put this code.

Comment: I used onGridReady() callback function. :)

Comment: could you please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65410978/how-to-build-a-lookup-search-functin-using-ag-grid-customfiltercomponent

Answer (score 0):

Check this StackBlitz: [Custom placeholder with ag-grid](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j7mmxi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-filter.component.ts). The Make column has a custom filter.

In your `app.module.ts`:

```
imports:[ BrowserModule, FormsModule, AgGridModule.withComponents([CustomFilterComponent]) ]
```

In your HTML file:

```
<ag-grid-angular 
    style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" 
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [enableSorting]="true"
    [enableFilter]="true"
    [rowData]="rowData" 
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
    >
</ag-grid-angular>
```

In your TS file:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  private frameworkComponents;

  constructor() {
    this.frameworkComponents = { customFilter: CustomFilterComponent };
  }

  columnDefs = [
    {headerName: 'Make', field: 'make', filter: "customFilter" },
    {headerName: 'Model', field: 'model' },
    {headerName: 'Price', field: 'price'}
  ];

  rowData = [
    { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000 }
  ];
}
```

In your `custom-filter.component.ts` file:

```
import {Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef} from "@angular/core";

import {IAfterGuiAttachedParams, IDoesFilterPassParams, IFilterParams, RowNode} from "ag-grid-community";
import {IFilterAngularComp} from "ag-grid-angular";

@Component({
    selector: 'filter-cell',
    template: `
        <div class="container">
            Custom Filter: <input #input (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" [ngModel]="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Custom placeholder">
        </div>
    `, styles: [
        `
            .container {
                border: 2px solid #22ff22;
                border-radius: 5px;
                background-color: #bbffbb;
                width: 200px;
                height: 50px
            }

            input {
                height: 20px
            }
        `
    ]
})
export class CustomFilterComponent implements IFilterAngularComp {
  private params: IFilterParams;
    private valueGetter: (rowNode: RowNode) => any;
    public text: string = '';

    @ViewChild('input', {read: ViewContainerRef}) public input;

    agInit(params: IFilterParams): void {
        this.params = params;
        this.valueGetter = params.valueGetter;
    }

    isFilterActive(): boolean {
        return this.text !== null && this.text !== undefined && this.text !== '';
    }

    doesFilterPass(params: IDoesFilterPassParams): boolean {
        return this.text.toLowerCase()
            .split(" ")
            .every((filterWord) => {
                return this.valueGetter(params.node).toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(filterWord) >= 0;
            });
    }

    getModel(): any {
        return {value: this.text};
    }

    setModel(model: any): void {
        this.text = model ? model.value : '';
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(params: IAfterGuiAttachedParams): void {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.input.element.nativeElement.focus();
        })
    }

    onChange(newValue): void {
        if (this.text !== newValue) {
            this.text = newValue;
            this.params.filterChangedCallback();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So we are creating a complete custom filter just  to change a 'Placeholder text' right ?

Comment: could ypu plaes help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65410978/how-to-build-a-lookup-search-functin-using-ag-grid-customfiltercomponent

Answer (score 0):

For those looking at this presently, top answer is out of date. AG Grid now allows a `localeText` parameter be passed, through which we can set `searchOoo` to override this text.

ie:

```
<AgGridReact
  [...]
  localeText={{
    searchOoo: 'Find...',
  }}
/>
```

*(example is React but applies to Angular as well)*

See https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/localisation/.

Comment: Worth noting that this property will apply to all columns, so you can't have different locale per column with this approach.